# Android app unable to launch an activity after splash activity

Tags: java, android

My app is unable to move to the 2nd activity that's StartingPoint after successfully launching the splash activity. App closes saying "unfortunately theNewBoston has stopped working."

I am attaching the relevant files. hope someone can help me with this. 
**StartingPoint.java**

```
  package com.example.thenewboston;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
    int counter;
    Button add,sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
        counter=0;
        add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subButton);
        display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is = " + counter);
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is = " + counter);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Splash.java**

```
    package com.example.thenewboston;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle TV) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(TV);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent openStatingPoint= new Intent("com.thenewboston.StartingPoint"); 
                    startActivity(openStatingPoint);

                }    

            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thenewboston"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity
            android:name=".StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.thenewboston.StartingPoint" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add the logcat of the crash.

Comment: @Sumeet Shah  just replace Intent openStatingPoint= new Intent("com.thenewboston.StartingPoint"); to Intent i = new Intent(
                                    this
                                    ,StartingPoint.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code as below:

```
 Intent openStatingPoint= new Intent(Splash.this,StartingPoint.class); 
                startActivity(openStatingPoint);
```

**Explanation:**

The constructor used here takes **two** parameters:
A **Context** as its first parameter (**Splash.this** is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)
The Class of the app component to which the system should deliver the Intent (in this case, the activity that should be started, here is **StartingPoint.class**)

See more [Build an Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent)

Comment: This is correct @pRaNay however instead of dumping the code please explain what you did so that future people can see the answer as well.

Comment: @basic Thanks. I am on edit and now answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Thread class doesn't work on **UI Thread** so that instead of using **Thread** class use **Handler** class as follows -

Splash.java

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
            Intent openStatingPoint= new Intent(Splash.this,StartingPoint.class);   // Use Explicit Intents
            startActivity(openStatingPoint);
            finish();
      }
    }, 5000);  //time in milliseconds
```

Answer (score -1):

check your logcat for the exception stack trace, it could be many reasons.
and

Comment: This should be a comment and adds nothing as an answer.